# angular 5 components changes in one component then reflect on other siblings

Tags: angular, components, observable, lifecycle, eventemitter

I have three Components A, B, C, they are all siblings. There is http.get method inside ComponentA(getting data from backend), them using dependency injection and eventemitter to pass data from A to B and A to C. Now, my problem is if I make some changes in Component B, how can I trigger the changes in Component C

Here is Function in Component A, searchButtonInDropdown() invoked when click a Button:

```
searchButtonInDropdown() {
this.searchData.http.get(this.url).subscribe(Data => {
    this.showResults.parcelInformation.emit(Data);
}, error => {
  this.showError(error);
});
```

Here is Service to passing data between A to B, and A to C:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class PassResultsToResultsTableService {

   constructor() { }
    parcelInformation = new EventEmitter();  
 }
```

And B and C are subscribes the parcelInformation in service

Comment: Why not used a shared service for the data? Each component can subscribe to an observable / subject, and be notified of any changes.

Comment: did you means adding same http get request to each A, B, C?

Comment: Not quite, no. You can create a subject by doing `this.test = new Subject()` in a service. Each of your components can then subscribe (like yoiu do with an Http call). When any one of those components then does `service.test.next(value)`, each of the subscribe functions will then be called with the value of your `value` variable. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, not really... is there any examples? Thanks

Comment: I add some codes, would you please take a look? Thanks

Comment: Your example is pretty much there. Here is a StackBlitz example. The AppComponent emits a value ("Hello"), waits 5 seconds, then emits another value ("GoodBye"), and these value changes are shown in both the a and b components https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yosvrk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: not same, I think that one is A to B, and A to C, then A changed reflect on B and C, but mine is B changed then reflect on C